# Voice Guidance for Google Maps Route in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

My application calls Google Maps via an `Intent` to show best route between two points using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?dirflg=d&saddr=" + String.valueOf(currentPosition.getPosition().latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(currentPosition.getPosition().longitude) + "&daddr=" + String.valueOf(currentDest.getPosition().latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(currentDest.getPosition().longitude)));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

I was wondering, is it possible to activate voice guidance for the route via a parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for voice guidance and navigation

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="
                            +Destination));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: for this google navigation app will be required..and it will start a turn by turn voice guidance..using app intsalled on your device

Comment: How do you set source address?

Comment: source address will be your current location..you dont need to mention it

Comment: I tried your code, but no spoken directions are played back by my device. Is this a device or manufacturer specific issue? I'm using Sony XPERIA SP with JB 4.3

Comment: i tried it on samsung tab and nexus 5 it works good..may be it is a device issue.

Comment: Apparently both are, as PlayStore is not offering any updates

Comment: if this is the case..check the map and navigation app installed in your device..whether they provide voice guidance or not..if not then..it is the problem with both of these apps

Comment: I have no navigation software installed on my cell phone, and Google Map does not provide voice guidance (at least I have no idea how to enable it) :-(

Comment: then install navigation app...and use a check in your app for nagitaion app..if it is installed then intent for navigation should be called...and if not then intent for google maps should be called..